# background image (svg) is not loading in ReactJS project

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, jsx

I am making a project in ReactJS. And I am using inline CSS to set background image to my main element which is svg. But this is not loading in the live preview. I have tried many ways available on the internet but still this is not working.

`

```
function Questionnaire(props){

     const styles = {
                backgroundImage : "url(/images/background.svg)",
                backgroundPosition: "center center",
                backgroundSize: "cover"
              }

     return(
            <main style={styles}>
            </main>
       
           )
}
```

`

If I'm moving my images folder to src folder, then it is showing me this error[Error shown in React project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eaDyx.png).

Answer (score 2):

you need to import the image above, then you can add in the background image `url`, as you can see the below code.

```
import BackgroundImage from '/images/background.svg';

function Questionnaire(props){

 const styles = {
            backgroundImage : `url(${BackgroundImage})`,
            backgroundPosition: "center center",
            backgroundSize: "cover"
          }

 return(
        <main style={styles}>
        </main>
   
       )
}
```

Comment: After doing this, the browser shows me this error.                                                               
                                                                                                                                 
Compiled with problems:X

ERROR in ./src/App.js 10:0-53

Module not found: Error: You attempted to import /images/background.svg which falls outside of the project src/ directory. Relative imports outside of src/ are not supported.
You can either move it inside src/, or add a symlink to it from project's node_modules/.

Comment: you need to put the image in `src` folder and then you need to give the full path here `/images/background.svg`, please try this.

Answer (score 0):

your path is not correct and make sure you enter the Right file name

Answer (score 0):

First of all it is based on the version of React in your project. If your assets in public directory next to index.html, then you are good to go. But I think React 17 and above does not support local path for assets in src folder. You need to import the image above and use it where you want to use it or you can require it with local path. And One more thing is that React uses relative import by default. If you enable absolute import feature, then You can use.
Overall:

```
import BgImage from 'path/to/image/'; //relative or abslute path

    function Questionnaire(props){
    
         const styles = {
                    backgroundImage : `url(${BgImage}`, // first option
                    backgroundImage : `url(${require('path/to/image')}`, // second option
                    backgroundPosition: "center center",
                    backgroundSize: "cover"
                  }
    
         return(
                <main style={styles}>
                </main>
               )
    }
```